# Connect to Azure Batch service from browser jQuery ajax REST call

Tags: jquery, rest, azure, sharepoint-2013, azure-batch

I have access to an Azure batch service with the account name and base64 authentication key. A coworker wrote a batch service that retrieves files, processes them, and returns them to a specified location. These files are stored in a SharePoint library, and the batch service works fine. What we would like to do, is from the browser, setup an ajax call in jQuery/ajax to properly create the correct headers and the proper authentication information to perform this request. I have found some documentation but no real examples that work because I primarily end up with an error:

The MAC signature found in the HTTP request  is not the same as any computed signature.

It displays what it uses to create a key so I thought I would do that same thing but it still doesn't work and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Glad that Batch service part is working great.

WIth regards to the error message: `"The MAC signature found in the HTTP request is not the same as any computed signature."` Every request made against a storage service must be authenticated, In this case its related with the Authentication for Azure Storage.

- You probably want to carefully get the `url` you are forming.
- Key documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Authentication-for-the-Azure-Storage-Services?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Also, please take a look at the similar issue happened in past here:

- [The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '...' is not the same as any computed signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465420/the-mac-signature-found-in-the-http-request-is-not-the-same-as-any-compute)
- [C# Azure REST API : The MAC signature [...] is not the same as any computed signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570357/c-sharp-azure-rest-api-the-mac-signature-is-not-the-same-as-any-computed)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ee551d65-ecd6-4e6c-9da9-a412f98b7c8b/blob-rest-authentication-examples?forum=windowsazuredata
- [The MAC signature found in the HTTP request is not the same as any computed signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702744/the-mac-signature-found-in-the-http-request-is-not-the-same-as-any-computed-sign)

> Authentication for Azure Storage is not simply a matter of providing
>   the access key (that is not very secure). You need to create a
>   signature string that represents the given request, sign the string
>   with the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm (using your storage key to sign), and
>   encode the result in base 64. See
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx for full
>   details, including how to construct the signature string.

Comment: Thanks for this response! I had found most of these but none of them seem to help me get an answer for doing this in web browser javascript/jQuery. I am sure that much of that is because of the need to perform various conversions between base64 and UTF8 but no real examples on using web based javascript to do it. I may end having to use c# from a service and just send an ajax call to that but not sure.

Comment: Cool, no probs at all! `:)` If you have any code to share then feel free. Thanks